# Ajax POST returning empty string

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been trying to access data from another site by ajax but failed.
The scenario is if i post data to the site by a form then i am redirected to the site and displays correct data.
What I want to do is I want my script to fetch that data using ajax.
One thing i want to clear that I cant modify the script on the server side so that i can add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Is their any trick or hack so that I get the data???

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://somedomain.com/FlightStatus.aspx',
                    data: {ArrFltStatus:'KDU',DepFltStatus:'ISB',DropDownDay:'today',Submit:'Proceed'},
                     success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error:function(xhr,err){
                        alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                        alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: As security precaution cross origin requests are blocked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they have a JSONp interface, use it (that won't work with POST though).

Otherwise you need proxy script on your server which performs the remote access so your JavaScript can access a resource on the same domain.

Comment: Does'nt matter what it accepts, it's blocked by the browser as a security measure. Only JSONP is allowed, and JSONP only supports GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

When requesting cross domain resources you should use the dataType: 'jsonp' attribute in your ajax options.

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced same issue when I was using script to retrieve data on local macine, but I get this working properly when I uploaded my calling script on the server from where I was requesting the data...

It is because of domain security, which was not allowing me to retrieve data from the hosting server..

Comment: ok, so the remote server is same from which you are trying to retieve data using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain requests can only be done with JSONP, and JSONP only supports GET, and $.ajax defaults to GET, so no need to set a type at all:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://somedomain.com/FlightStatus.aspx',
   data: {ArrFltStatus:'KDU',DepFltStatus:'ISB',DropDownDay:'today',Submit:'Proceed'},
   dataType : 'jsonp',
}).done(function(data) {
     alert(data);
});
```

Error handler is not fired with JSONP, so no need to use that either.

If the service you are requesting data from does not support JSONP, you can use Yahoo's YQL to set up a pipe that will let you get the data in JSONP format.